# NGRX state update

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

this is my State:-

```
roles =[ {
roleId:"8e8be141-130d-4e5c-82d2-0a642d4b73e1"
name:"HR"
description:"HR of the Company"
isModerator:"N"
},
{
roleId:"8e8be141-130d-4e5c-82d2-0a642d4b73e1"
name:"MR"
description:"MR of the Company"
isModerator:"Y"
}]
```

this is My reducer:-

```
on(updateRoleItem, (s, { roleId, item }) => {
        let modifiedState = [...s];
        modifiedState.map((data) => {
            if (data.roleId === roleId) {
                data.name = item;
            }
        })
        return modifiedState;
    })
);
```

this is what error I am getting:-
[image]

I want to update the name property of role in array of roles. So I am finding the object
by roleId and then updating the name but I am getting error. Can Someone help me with the right way of doing it?

Comment: `let modifiedState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([...s]))` I am not sure this is correct way to doing it or not

Answer (score 1):

By default the NgRx state (and actions) are [immutable](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks#runtime-checks).
Which means you can't simply update the properties, but you must create a clone first.
To do this, you can use the rest spread syntax.
You could also use [ngrx-immer](https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-immer#readme).

```
on(updateRoleItem, (s, { roleId, item }) => {
        return s.map(data => {
          if (data.roleId === roleId) {
                return {...data, name: item };
          }
          return data;
        });
    })
);
```

with ngrx-immer

```
immerOn(updateRoleItem, (s, { roleId, item }) => {
    
        s.map((data) => {
            if (data.roleId === roleId) {
                data.name = item;
            }
        })
    })
);
```